# PostSharp Aspect Libraries

Tags: windows, software-development, visual-studio

I own a [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) license. PostSharp is a IL code weaver for .NET in order to achieve aspect oriented programming (AOP).

Depending on the edition, PostSharp comes with more or less aspects included, but in any case, I can think of many more aspects that could be implemented with PostSharp but are not delivered by default.

Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I'm interested in libraries that bring new PostSharp aspects. I am not looking for particular aspects, I'd just have a look at all the suggestions and find out whether I can apply them to my project(s) or not.

Requirements (otherwise the question would be too broad) for the aspects:

- must work with PostSharp 4.2
- must not be WPF aspects
- may be WinForms aspects
- must work with .NET 4.0 or higher (.NET 2.0 support highly appreciated)
- cost less than 35 € / 40 USD
- perpetual license if commercial
- if no commercial support is available, it should be open source in order to be able to make bug fixes

Examples of potential aspects which are IMHO not included in PostSharp Ultimate:

- Stopwatch (performance analysis)
- Mouse Cursor (e.g. hourglass)
- ETW Logging (Event Tracing for Windows)
- Memory Gate (ensure enough memory is available)
- Slowdown (sleep, e.g. for demo versions)
- Garbage Collect (before/after a method)
- UAC (save app state and restart as admin)

I am *not* looking for

- Logging or monitoring aspects such as [PubComp](https://pubcomp.codeplex.com/) since that's the too obvious use case of AOP and implemented many times already
- Aspects bundled to a commercial product, such as [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/pricing/), [Loupe](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/loupe/features) or [ReflectInside](http://www.reflectsoftware.com/Public/Products/ReflectInsight/Overview.aspx). BTW they are all logging aspects at the same time and violate the price requirement.
- alternatives to PostSharp such as [SheepAspect](https://sheepaspect.codeplex.com/) or [Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought) since I have a PostSharp license and I am used to it.

Candidates not qualifying due to missing documentation:

- [Contracts Killer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoingPostal.ContractsKiller/)
- [PostSharp-Aspects](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/PostSharp-Aspects) (doesn't even have a list of provided aspects)
- [MVVM Light Binding Attributes](https://github.com/spoqa/MvvmLightBindingAttributes)

Comment: Could you please tell us what is wrong with SmartInspect, Loupe, ReflectInside? Please add this information inside your question, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That makes the question clearer :-)

Comment: I know you specify PostSharp, but have you looked into [Fody](https://github.com/Fody) at all? Its open source and pretty well documented. It has some of what you are asking and I'm sure they'd accept contributions for the others.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Wow, Fody has made good progress since I last looked into it (long time ago)